# How to make the animation run in the background? html/css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

so I have the following animation:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('nokey'),
   can_w = parseInt(canvas.getAttribute('width')),
   can_h = parseInt(canvas.getAttribute('height')),
   ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// console.log(typeof can_w);

var ball = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      vx: 0,
      vy: 0,
      r: 0,
      alpha: 1,
      phase: 0
   },
   ball_color = {
       r: 207,
       g: 255,
       b: 4
   },
   R = 2,
   balls = [],
   alpha_f = 0.03,
   alpha_phase = 0,
    
// Line
   link_line_width = 0.8,
   dis_limit = 260,
   add_mouse_point = true,
   mouse_in = false,
   mouse_ball = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      vx: 0,
      vy: 0,
      r: 0,
      type: 'mouse'
   };

// Random speed
function getRandomSpeed(pos){
    var  min = -1,
       max = 1;
    switch(pos){
        case 'top':
            return [randomNumFrom(min, max), randomNumFrom(0.1, max)];
            break;
        case 'right':
            return [randomNumFrom(min, -0.1), randomNumFrom(min, max)];
            break;
        case 'bottom':
            return [randomNumFrom(min, max), randomNumFrom(min, -0.1)];
            break;
        case 'left':
            return [randomNumFrom(0.1, max), randomNumFrom(min, max)];
            break;
        default:
            return;
            break;
    }
}
function randomArrayItem(arr){
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}
function randomNumFrom(min, max){
    return Math.random()*(max - min) + min;
}
console.log(randomNumFrom(0, 10));
// Random Ball
function getRandomBall(){
    var pos = randomArrayItem(['top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left']);
    switch(pos){
        case 'top':
            return {
                x: randomSidePos(can_w),
                y: -R,
                vx: getRandomSpeed('top')[0],
                vy: getRandomSpeed('top')[1],
                r: R,
                alpha: 1,
                phase: randomNumFrom(0, 10)
            }
            break;
        case 'right':
            return {
                x: can_w + R,
                y: randomSidePos(can_h),
                vx: getRandomSpeed('right')[0],
                vy: getRandomSpeed('right')[1],
                r: R,
                alpha: 1,
                phase: randomNumFrom(0, 10)
            }
            break;
        case 'bottom':
            return {
                x: randomSidePos(can_w),
                y: can_h + R,
                vx: getRandomSpeed('bottom')[0],
                vy: getRandomSpeed('bottom')[1],
                r: R,
                alpha: 1,
                phase: randomNumFrom(0, 10)
            }
            break;
        case 'left':
            return {
                x: -R,
                y: randomSidePos(can_h),
                vx: getRandomSpeed('left')[0],
                vy: getRandomSpeed('left')[1],
                r: R,
                alpha: 1,
                phase: randomNumFrom(0, 10)
            }
            break;
    }
}
function randomSidePos(length){
    return Math.ceil(Math.random() * length);
}

// Draw Ball
function renderBalls(){
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(balls, function(b){
       if(!b.hasOwnProperty('type')){
           ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba('+ball_color.r+','+ball_color.g+','+ball_color.b+','+b.alpha+')';
           ctx.beginPath();
           ctx.arc(b.x, b.y, R, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
           ctx.closePath();
           ctx.fill();
       }
    });
}

// Update balls
function updateBalls(){
    var new_balls = [];
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(balls, function(b){
        b.x += b.vx;
        b.y += b.vy;
        
        if(b.x > -(50) && b.x < (can_w+50) && b.y > -(50) && b.y < (can_h+50)){
           new_balls.push(b);
        }
        
        // alpha change
        b.phase += alpha_f;
        b.alpha = Math.abs(Math.cos(b.phase));
        // console.log(b.alpha);
    });
    
    balls = new_balls.slice(0);
}

// loop alpha
function loopAlphaInf(){
    
}

// Draw lines
function renderLines(){
    var fraction, alpha;
    for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < balls.length; j++) {
           
           fraction = getDisOf(balls[i], balls[j]) / dis_limit;
            
           if(fraction < 1){
               alpha = (1 - fraction).toString();

               ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(150,150,150,'+alpha+')';
               ctx.lineWidth = link_line_width;
               
               ctx.beginPath();
               ctx.moveTo(balls[i].x, balls[i].y);
               ctx.lineTo(balls[j].x, balls[j].y);
               ctx.stroke();
               ctx.closePath();
           }
        }
    }
}

// calculate distance between two points
function getDisOf(b1, b2){
    var  delta_x = Math.abs(b1.x - b2.x),
       delta_y = Math.abs(b1.y - b2.y);
    
    return Math.sqrt(delta_x*delta_x + delta_y*delta_y);
}

// add balls if there a little balls
function addBallIfy(){
    if(balls.length < 20){
        balls.push(getRandomBall());
    }
}

// Render
function render(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can_w, can_h);
    
    renderBalls();
    
    renderLines();
    
    updateBalls();
    
    addBallIfy();
    
    window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

// Init Balls
function initBalls(num){
    for(var i = 1; i <= num; i++){
        balls.push({
            x: randomSidePos(can_w),
            y: randomSidePos(can_h),
            vx: getRandomSpeed('top')[0],
            vy: getRandomSpeed('top')[1],
            r: R,
            alpha: 1,
            phase: randomNumFrom(0, 10)
        });
    }
}
// Init Canvas
function initCanvas(){
    canvas.setAttribute('width', window.innerWidth);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', window.innerHeight);
    
    can_w = parseInt(canvas.getAttribute('width'));
    can_h = parseInt(canvas.getAttribute('height'));
}
window.addEventListener('resize', function(e){
    console.log('Window Resize...');
    initCanvas();
});

function goMovie(){
    initCanvas();
    initBalls(30);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
goMovie();

// Mouse effect
canvas.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
    console.log('mouseenter');
    mouse_in = true;
    balls.push(mouse_ball);
});
canvas.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    console.log('mouseleave');
    mouse_in = false;
    var new_balls = [];
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(balls, function(b){
        if(!b.hasOwnProperty('type')){
            new_balls.push(b);
        }
    });
    balls = new_balls.slice(0);
});
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    var e = e || window.event;
    mouse_ball.x = e.pageX;
    mouse_ball.y = e.pageY;
    // console.log(mouse_ball);
});
```

```css
*{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
}
canvas{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="nokey" width="800" height="800">
```

How would I make this animation run in the background of lets say text, image...etc? Right now, this animation has its own section and the text or the image gets moved away for this animation to run.

This is what happens:

[image]

But I want the "My Story" to be in its exact position and this animation run behind it, how would I go about doing that? I tried playing with the code in `js` since that's mostly what controls it, but I cannot seem to figure it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: make your canvas z-index negative and make position absolute , i hope it will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following properties to Canvas:

```
z-index: -1;
position: absolute;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

z-index: -1:

> Overlapping elements with a larger z-index cover those with a smaller one

so you can set the 'z-index' of canvas to a negative value, like -1.

position: absolute:

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout

Setting the canvas position to absolute makes it impossible to push other elements away

[image: Effect]